# Is it possible to dump memory after every instruction?

Tags: c, linux

I want to visualize memory. I'm thinking to dump the memory of a c program (or the kernel if thats possible, but I suspect it isn't) after every instruction, visualize it and then stack each frame to make a small animation. I know how to do the visualization part but not how to safely dump memory without halting execution.

Is this at all possible?

Comment: A debugger is doing this. Use `gdb`

Comment: You realize you typically execute a billion instructions per second right? Now multiply that by the size of your memory. I think you'll exhaust your storage in a manner of seconds... And good luck finding a way to analyze that much data.

Answer (score 1):

If you can run DTrace on your version of Linux, then you could use something like tracemem() to print a specific address without stopping the program (unlike a debugger)

But as a comment above says, dumping all the application memory after each instruction would generate too much info...

[disclaimer, I've only used DTrace under Solaris]